# Is there a way to match values between two vectors without iterating step-wise through the vector in R

Tags: r, for-loop, matching

I have date and ozone values in a time series of multiple years that I am dividing into seasons (DJF, MAM, JJA, SON). To divide the data into years I am first dividing the data into years that start in March and end in February. I am matching values between a vector of dates and the years it should be divided into. However, when the loop runs it iterates by looking at the first value in the date vector, followed by the first and second, followed by the first, second, and the third. Is there a way for it to grab all matching values at once instead of iterating in this fashion? I have created a small subset of my data and included it below so the code is entirely reproducible. My script is below:

```
library(lubridate)
MAM <- c(03, 04, 05)
JJA <- c(06, 07, 08)
SON <- c(09, 10, 11)
DJF <- c(12, 01, 02)
JF <- c(01, 02)
MtoD <- c(03, 04, 05, 06, 07, 08, 09, 10, 11, 12)
ozn <- c(14, 15, NA, 20, 21, NA, NA, 34) 
seasons <- c("MAM", "JJA", "SON", "DJF")
dts <- c("1998-01-05", "1998-03-06", "1999-04-12", "1999-05-10", "2000-02-03", "2000-03-21", "2000-11-09", "2000-12-07")

yearlist <- c('1997', '1998', '1999', '2000')
yearlist <- as.Date(yearlist, "%Y")
names(dts) <- ozn
seasonyearlist <- c()
totalNA <- c()
percentNA <- c()
oneseason <- c()
seasonalyear1 <- c()
seasonalyear2 <- c()
for (d in as.character(yearlist)) {
  theyears <- format.Date(d, "%Y")
  oneyear <- c()
  for (d in (dts)){
    if (year(d) %in% theyears){
      oneyear <- c(oneyear,d)
      print(oneyear)}
     }
```

The issue is in the if statement. When I print "oneyear' it looks like this:

```
[1] "1998-01-05"
[1] "1998-01-05" "1998-03-06"
[1] "1999-04-12"
[1] "1999-04-12" "1999-05-10"
[1] "2000-02-03"
[1] "2000-02-03" "2000-03-21"
[1] "2000-02-03" "2000-03-21" "2000-11-09"
[1] "2000-02-03" "2000-03-21" "2000-11-09" "2000-12-07"
```

Comment: If all you want to do is to find matches between two vectors `match`could be worth a look. Though looking at your example I get the feeling it's a bit more involved, yet  I can't quite figure out how. Your code confuses me. What is the underlying problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: My understanding is that match only returns the first match between two vectors. I am using %in% because it is more flexible and returns all matches. Ultimately, I want oneyear to be returns as all dates in that year and not the first, followed by the first and second, etc. I think finding someway of doing that will also increase speed.

Comment: So the underlying problem you want to solve is how to group dates by year, and the method you have tried so far is to find matches between two vectors, one containing the dates, the other containing the years?

Comment: If you could edit your question to remove all extraneous information, and include a mock-up of what you'd really want the for loop to output, that would help immensely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this more or less the type of output you're looking for?

```
library(lubridate)
set.seed(1)
dates <- sort(as.Date(sample(1:1500, 20), origin="1997-01-05"))
split(dates, year(dates))

$`1997`
[1] "1997-04-08" "1997-09-25" "1997-11-03" "1997-11-08"

$`1998`
[1] "1998-02-08" "1998-07-17" "1998-07-23" "1998-07-31"

$`1999`
[1] "1999-01-15" "1999-05-14" "1999-08-02" "1999-09-19" "1999-10-25" "1999-12-06"

$`2000`
[1] "2000-02-23" "2000-03-02" "2000-09-10" "2000-09-26" "2000-11-17"

$`2001`
[1] "2001-01-15"
```

Comment: I found another work around but this would have worked as well. Thanks so much for your help!